# com.android.volley.noconnectionerror:javax.net.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: android-volley

who knows how can solves this problem?

com.android.volley.noconnectionerror:javax.net.SSLHandshakeException:java.security.cert.CertPathVaildatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

private static String URL_REGIST = "https://192.168.1.126/functions.php";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("successs");
                        //Log.d("123: " ,  response);
                        if (success.equals("1")){
                            Toast.makeText(RegistActivity.this,"Register Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //Log.e("456: ", response);
                        Toast.makeText(RegistActivity.this,"Register Error! " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        accountloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistActivity.this,"Register Error! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        accountloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("lastname", lastname);
                params.put("firstname", firstname);
                params.put("nickname", nickname);
                params.put("password", password);
                //params.put("birthday", birthday);
                params.put("email", email);
                //params.put("phone", phone);
                return params;
            }
        };
```

I don't know what's happening.

below is my php code and it's can link to DB. But I dont know what get errors.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password'];
        //$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //$phone = $_POST['phone'];


        $password1 = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        require_once 'connect.php';

       $sql = "INSERT INTO user (lastname, firstname, nickname, password1, email) 
        VALUES 
        ('$lastname','$firstname', '$nickname', '$password1', '$email')";

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO user (lastname, firstname, nickname, password1, birthday, email, phone) 
        //VALUES 
        //('$lastname','$firstname', '$nickname', '$password1', '$birthday', '$email', '$phone')";



        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            $result["success"] = "1";
            $result["message"] = "Success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
        } else {
            $result["success"] = "0";
            $result["message"] = "Error";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using `private static String URL_REGIST = "https://192.168.1.126/functions.php";` as URL.

But your local IP address *192.168.1.126* does not have a valid SSL certificate.
To fix this you can use *http* instead of *https* for your local URL.

Please note, you should still use *https* when deploying to a real server if you have a valid SSL certificate for your real URL.